# Linq shortening

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is it possible to shorten this function into a single line / couple of lines?

```
Public Function countrySelector() As List(Of String)
    Dim myString As New List(Of String)
    Dim countryTitle As List(Of Entities.AttributeValue) = _PageVals.Where(Function(x) x.TabDescription = "Country").ToList()
    myString = countryTitle.Where(Function(x) x.AttributeId = Entities.AttributeTypes.TITLE).Select(Function(y) y.Value).ToList()
    Return myString
End Function
```

Comment: Number of lines does not equal quality. Good quality code is easy to read, understand and maintain. Properly written 10 lines of code may be better than 1 that spans 3 horizontal screens. You will do yourself a favor by avoiding a habit of fitting everything in one line. Other developers will thank you for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
myString  = _PageVals.Where(Function(x) x.TabDescription = "Country" AndAlso x.AttributeId = Entities.AttributeTypes.TITLE).Select(Function(y) y.Value).ToList()
```

Comment: This looks more like C# than VB.

Comment: I changed it in VB.NET Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
Return _PageVals _ 
  .Where(Function(x) x.TabDescription = "Country") _
  .Where(Function(x) x.AttributeId = Entities.AttributeTypes.TITLE) _
  .Select(Function(y) y.Value) _
  .ToList()
```

Comment: +1. Voted best for ease of reading. A side note: VB10+ supports implicit line continuation after `.` character, so you don't need `_`.

Comment: @Neolisk yeah I wasn't quite sure which version they were using hence I used the explicit separators

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this way

```
myString  = (From C in _PageVals Where C.TabDescription = "Country" AndAlso C.AttributeId = Entities.AttributeTypes.TITLE Select C.Value).ToList()
```